# Dropzone upload in background (PHP)

Tags: javascript, dropzone.js, dropzone

I'm trying to upload multiple large files at once with Dropzone. I want to do so in asynchronous way.

It means, when I drop the files into Dropzone I want all of them to start uploading right away and at the same time I want to be able to leave the page (while uploading still continues).

When I drop multiple files now, they start to upload, but I cannot change the page immediately - the browser is waiting for the first file to be uploaded, then it finally goes to another page.

Is it possible to do the above with Dropzone? Is there some other way how to do this in PHP? Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

> I want all of them to start uploading right away and at the same time
>   I want to be able to leave the page (while uploading still continues).

Leave the page while uploading isn't possible.

A solution would be to use a singe page application, so you have never to reload the hole page. If you only change the content, it is possible to sill upload the content.